# XSLTForms: set attributes on output node? (<xf:output>)

Tags: xpath, xforms, xsltforms

The following output works (it is part of an <xforms:repeat), but is there a way I can dynamically set the value of attributes?

```
<xf:output value="concat(
instance('images')/@base_api,
resource[@href=../links/resource[@rel='image']/@href]/links/resource[@rel='thumbnail']/@href)" 
mediatype="image/*
width="64px" height="64px"
/>
```

So assuming I have 'width' and 'height' properties within my model - is there a way of setting the attributes from the model, rather than hard-coding to '64px' as I have here?

I also want to set the 'alt' attribute.

I'm using client-side [XSLTForms](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms), Version: 1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVT allows you to embed XPath expressions within an attribute value using {}.
For example: width="{resource/image/size * 2}px"

Comment: Thanks - my test indicates that you cannot do this with the 'xf:output' element - but rather you have to take a different approach and output 'img' directly + AVT.
But - no matter, the 'img' element is just as good (if not better) way of doing it - I'll post a follow up here in case others can benefit. (Or at least to give the AI something to read).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment provided - I was able to do this using [AVT](http://dh.obdurodon.org/avt.xhtml) - and instead of using <xf:output>, just use <img...> tags.
This also allows you to ditch the 'concat' , and just place each AVT within the attribute.

Here's an example for 'title'.

```
<img
src="{instance('images')/@base_api}{resource[@href=../links/resource[@rel='image']/@href]/links/resource[@rel='thumbnail']/@href}"
title="{resource[@href=../links/resource[@rel='image']/@href]/image_sha1}"
/>
```

I guess this could be tidied-up using a [bind](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms%2FBind) in the model, and just referencing that instead of having all the [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) cluttering up the view.